# VLOOKUP functionality in Excel

Tags: excel

K      L     M

C1     C2    Result

100    10    `=VLOOKUP(L2,$K$2:$K$4,1,TRUE) output is: 1`

1      2     `=VLOOKUP(L2,$K$2:$K$4,1,TRUE) output is: 1`

1      3     `=VLOOKUP(L2,$K$2:$K$4,1,TRUE) output is: 1`

As the values in C1 and C2 change, the output value changes under Result.

Like, for the below values:

C1     C2    Result

100    10    0

2      2     2

0      3     0

From the definition of Vlookup "**If TRUE or omitted, an exact or approximate match is returned. If an exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less than lookup_value is returned.**", it says that *If an exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less than lookup_value is returned.*

So in the above example as per the def'n, against 10, shouldn't the answer be 2 instead of 0.

Well if the values change as shown below, as per the def'n I am assuming the result against 3 should be 2 but it displays 1.

C1     C2    Result

100    10    1

2      2     2

1      3     1

I am trying to know a bit about VLOOKUP function in Excel. Please help me understand it right.

Comment: Please improve the formatting and structure of your question. It's hard to understand at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overlooked this part in the HELP information:

> **Important:**   If range_lookup is either TRUE or is omitted, the values
>   in the first column of table_array must be placed in **ascending** sort
>   order; otherwise, VLOOKUP might not return the correct value

Comment: thank you very much for pointing out what I missed. Appreciate your help.